# Why do we account for exchangeability of IID variables before the complement?

Tags: probability, random-variables

The question is: A piece of wood 1 meter in length is cut at 2 uniformly randomly selected locations along the length of the wood. Find the probability the shortest piece of wood is at most 5 centimeters.

The solution is below:

[image]

My (incorrect) understanding of the solution is that we have 2 cases:

1. $X < Y$
2. $X > Y$.

For case 1, we want to obtain the following probability:
$P[min(X, Y-X, 1-Y) < 0.05]$ and for case 2 we want $P[min(Y, X-Y, 1-X) < 0.05]$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are IID, they are exchangeable. Therefore, we can simply take $2P[min(Y, X-Y, 1-X) < 0.05]$ as our final answer

Now, in order to utilize the properties of the minimum, we take the complement of $P[min(Y, X-Y, 1-X) < 0.05]$ and get $1 - P[min(Y, X-Y, 1-X) \geq 0.05]$. Based on the exchangeability of $X$ and $Y$ mentioned above, our final answer would be $2*(1 - P[min(Y, X-Y, 1-X) \geq 0.05])$.

We then obtain $P[min(Y, X-Y, 1-X) \geq 0.05] = 289/800$ using the methodology provided in the solution, which means that $1 - P[min(Y, X-Y, 1-X) \geq 0.05] = P[min(Y, X-Y, 1-X) < 0.05] = 511/800$ and $2*511/800 = 511/400$ is our final answer, which is obviously incorrect.

The solution does $1 - 2P[min(Y, X-Y, 1-X) \geq 0.05] = 1 - 289/400$. My question is, why would you multiply the probability by 2 before taking the complement? Am I misunderstanding the application of exchangeabilty here? Any clarifying response is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question says that the joint probability of the following three events occurring together is $\frac12(1-\frac{10}{100}-\frac{5}{100})^2=\frac{289}{800}$:

- $X > 0.05$
- $Y > X+0.05$
- $1-Y > 0.05$

though there is a fourth event $Y>X$ assumed, which certainly occurs if the second does.

That is the area of the pink area below and you want to exclude this as all the lengths will be over $0.05$ metres.  But you also want to exclude the orange area, and exchangeability allows you to say that too is $\frac{289}{800}$, so the blue area you do want is $1-2\times \frac{289}{800} =\frac{111}{400}$.

[image]